# Can't find theme for configuration Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm trying the edit a theme i've uploaded via FTP to the APP & PUB folders.

However, I've checked under Content and Configuration and nothing is displayed. Not even the default theme. See attached. [image]

I've tried to filter the option to only show my Store but still nothing shows to select any theme.

The themes are installed properly because I can see them under Content, Themes. I can see the default themes and the custom theme.

Any help will be great

Comment: Could you share the contents of the `registration.php` and `theme.xml` files inside the theme you installed (found in the root of the theme `app/design/frontend/{{vender}}/{{theme}}/`) . While you might be seeing the theme listed in the Content -> Themes section, it sounds like the theme is still not configured correctly.

Comment: Sure, the registration.php contents:                                                                         ?php
/**
* Copyright © 2016 SW-THEMES. All rights reserved.
*/

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Smartwave/porto',
    __DIR__
);

Comment: theme.xml contents: <!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 SW-THEMES. All rights reserved.
*/
-->
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Smartwave Porto</title>
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>

Comment: I've fixed the issue. It was a reindex issue on the design Config Grid.

Comment: nice! can you post this as the answer to the question, in case someone comes across the same issue in the future?

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed the issue. It was a reindex issue on the Design Config Grid index.